# How can I generate a list of modified hyperlinks based on user input

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

I'm trying to modify a list of URLs using either HTML or Javascript. I collected a list of sites that will embed any YouTube video. They look like this:

- http://music-dump.com/id/00000
- http://youtube-id.com/download/00000

  etc.

  I want to generate a list of new hyperlinks with the "00000" replaced with the userInput. The list should generate from a button click or on-the-fly user typing. So far I found this:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeText2(){
    var userInput = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
    var lnk = document.getElementById('lnk');
    lnk.href = "http://music-dump.com/id/" + userInput;
    lnk.innerHTML = lnk.href; 
}
</script>
```

```html
Type the youtube code and click Open! <a href="" id=lnk>link</a> <br>
<input type='text' id='userInput' value='' />
<input type='submit' onclick='changeText2()' value='Open'/>
```

But this will only generate one link. I want a huge list. Is it possible?

Comment: Defiantly possible. Your going to want a target to place them all in and then to append the elements into it. You seem to understand how to get a target, to create and insert the elements check this: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp or use a library like jquery. Note this is a very simplified solution and is not optimal for performance, cross browser support, or maintainability.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
Type the youtube code and click Open! 
<div id="links">
</div>
<input type='text' id='userInput' value='' />
<input type='submit' onclick='changeText2()' value='Open'/>
```

And the javascript:

```
var links = [
    "http://music-dump.com/id/00000",
    "http://youtube-id.com/download/00000",
    "http://example.com/v/00000"
];

function changeText2() {
    var userInput = document.getElementById('userInput').value;

    links.forEach(function(link) {
        link = link.replace("00000", userInput);
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        a.href = link;
        a.innerHTML = link;
        document.getElementById('links').appendChild(a);
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u7hfuagw/2/

Comment: It's using jQuery, but you can do the same thing in pure javascript easily.

Comment: I have no idea how to jQuery, but the jsfiddle links works great!

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of your links in a list (hardcoded in your javascript file or retrieved from a service via XHR request for example). Then, for each link, insert a `<a>` tag in the DOM. Once the links are inserted, you only need to listen to the value of the input to update the `href` values ;)

HTML file:

```
<input type="text" id="userInput" placeholder="Start typing an ID...">
<ul id="links"></ul>
```

JS file:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  // the "huge" list of links
  var linksCollection = [
    'http://music-dump.com/id/{id}',
    'http://youtube-id.com/download/{id}'
  ];

  init();

  function init() {
    var li, a;

    // for each link in the collection, we are going to create
    // a <a> element within a <li> element
    for (var i = 0; i < linksCollection.length; i++) {
      li = document.createElement('li');
      a = document.createElement('a');

      a.href = linksCollection[i].replace('{id}', 0);
      a.innerHTML = a.href;

      li.appendChild(a);
      document
        .getElementById('links')
        .appendChild(li);
    }

    document
      .getElementById('userInput')
      .addEventListener('keyup', handleInput);
  }

  function handleInput() {
    var inputElement = document.getElementById('userInput');
    var links = document.getElementById('links').childNodes;
    var aElement;

    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
      aElement = links[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
      aElement.href = linksCollection[i].replace('{id}', inputElement.value);
      aElement.innerHTML = aElement.href;
    }
  }
})();
```

Link to the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/C1b6ccnpFrnNhDAsqxTF

PS: in the source code above, `<a>` are placed in a `<li>` tag for a better visual rendering. Feel free to place the `<a>` in other tags or to add class names for the styling. For example:

```
li = document.createElement('li');
li.className = 'list-item';
```